# Copyright Statements for Educational and Non-Commercial Use with Liability Disclaimer

Tags: copyright-display

I need guidance on creating comprehensive copyright statements and a liability disclaimer for sharing my code. Specifically, I require two different copyright statements: one for educational purposes only, limited to sharing with the professor, and another for non-commercial use, allowing sharing with others under certain conditions. Additionally, I would like to include a liability disclaimer.

## Copyright Statements

### For Educational Use (Limited to Professor)

I have drafted a copyright statement to protect my code when shared solely for educational purposes. It specifies that the code is exclusively intended for the designated professor and prohibits redistribution to other students or individuals not directly involved in the educational context.

> (c) Copyright [year] [name]. All rights reserved.
>
> This code is protected by copyright and is intended solely for
> educational purposes. It may only be accessed, used, and reviewed by
> the designated professor. Redistribution or sharing of this code with
> any third party, including other students or individuals not directly
> involved in the educational context, is strictly prohibited. Any
> unauthorized use or distribution is subject to legal consequences.

### For Non-Commercial Use (Requires Attribution and Share Alike)

I have also formulated a copyright statement for non-commercial use. It grants permission to share, distribute, and utilize the code, provided that proper attribution to my name is given whenever the code is referenced or used. Furthermore, any modifications or derivative works based on the code must be shared under the same terms, requiring attribution and disallowing commercial use.

> (c) Copyright [year] [name]. All rights reserved.
>
> This code is protected by copyright and is available for
> non-commercial use. You are permitted to share, distribute, and
> utilize this code, provided that proper attribution to [Your Name] is
> provided whenever the code is referenced or used. Additionally, any
> modifications, enhancements, or derivative works based on this code
> must be shared under the same terms, requiring attribution and
> prohibiting commercial use. All rights reserved.

## Liability Disclaimer

In addition to the copyright statements, I believe it is essential to include a liability disclaimer. The disclaimer should state that the shared code is provided "as is" without any warranties, and I disclaim any liability for damages arising from the use or inability to use the code. It should also highlight that I do not guarantee the accuracy, reliability, or completeness of the code and that users should proceed at their own risk.

> The code is provided "as is" without any warranty, express or implied.
> [Your Name] disclaims any liability for damages, including but not
> limited to direct, indirect, or consequential damages arising out of
> the use or inability to use this code. [Your Name] does not guarantee
> the accuracy, reliability, or completeness of the code and shall not
> be held responsible for any errors, omissions, or any loss resulting
> from the use of this code.

I would greatly appreciate any feedback, suggestions, or guidance on improving these copyright statements and liability disclaimer to ensure they adequately protect my code and align with the legal requirements. Thank you in advance for your assistance.